# Good Arduino motor drivers

Tags: motor, arduino-motor-shield

I need some motor drivers that can control a DC motor with 10-15 A and 25 V. I can't find any shield that can do the job. I need to control 4 motors with these.

Can you suggest some models that are good with this?

And one more question: if a driver can control a DC motor in 2 directions, can it control 2 DC motors in one direction each?

Comment: The "shield" form factor isn't really a good fit for these power levels.  Likely a suitable driver will be its own unit, which you will have to connect to the arduino with wires.

Answer (score 1):

We don't really answer "shopping questions".
You could contact several suppliers like [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/), [sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/) or maybe even [Digikey](http://digikey.com), [Farnell](http://www.farnell.com/) etc ([ebay](http://ebay.com)?).

If you search for: "15A dual h-bridge" you will find some motor drivers which should work for you.

**If a driver can control a dc motor in 2 directions can it control 2 dc motors in one direction each?**

Where are you going to use them for?
If you're only going in one direction, you won't need a motor driver.

An [MOSFET](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1794) (per motor) is good enough if you only drive one direction.
If you want both motors to be able to turn each direction, a [dual h-bridge](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-36V-Dual-15A-H-Bridge-DC-Motor-Driver-30A-for-Robot-Car-Arduino-Compatible-/171012036277) will do.

Comment: I need to control the speed

Comment: You can use `analogWrite(pin, value)` instead of digitalWrite. The value will be the "on time", so a lower value will make the motor go slower.

Comment: Nice but can I output around 25 V?

Comment: If you use a MOSFET that's rated for over 25V, yes. You'll also need a 25V power supply.

Comment: Think of the MOSFET as an on/off switch controlled by Arduino. But when you use analogWrite() it's more like a dimmer, for different speeds.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the current you need is high and you are not likely to get a shield that does that. Look at a H-bridge with the desired current and voltage rating, it will probable be largish with a heat sink. If the motors are going one way then you may just need a simple mosfet style driver. You should probably look for a module with the correct rating as it will have the correct heat sink, track sizes, connections for your motor power and will probably have a diode to protect stuff from the induction spikes.
The H bridge will probably be fine with the Arduino output and it may have a voltage reg for its logic that you could use to power the Arduino.